# Get an error when I use the cmdlets Set-Service

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Set-Service -Name TeamViewer -DisplayName Team Viewer

And I always get this error,even if I add double quotes on the name and the displayname

Set-Service: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument 'Viewer'.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-Service -Name TeamViewer -DisplayName Team Viewer
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Service], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
  ```

I have tried with double quotation

Set-Service -Name "TeamViewer" -DisplayName "Team Viewer"

Definitely used the hyphen before Name and DisplayName

And still get the same error.

Comment: I have tried this also, Set-Service -Name TeamViewer -DisplayName "Team Viewer" Getting access denied even though I am the admin of my Station.

Comment: "And still get the same error"  this is not true. The two different statement do produce another (not the same) error.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.